# Google Sheets: Returning a "Please seek additional resources" message in a cell if the calculated value is zero

Tags: google-sheets

I'm still working on ye-olde risk matrix. I need the Risk Calculation to spit out a number, but if they put in an unsure/unknown value (which I have assigned as 0 using SWITCH) it should calculate to zero. Instead of putting a 0 in the E column, I'd like it to show the phrase "Seek Additional Resources."

Here's what I have so far:

```
=IF("E7=0", "E7", "Seek Additional Resources"); 
SWITCH(C7,"Very Likely",4,"Likely",3,"Unlikely",2,"Very Unlikely",1, "Unknown/Unsure",0,0)*(SWITCH(D7, "Catastrophic",4,"Critical",3,"Moderate",2,"Negligible",1, "Unknown/Unsure",0,0))
```

Everything works until I stack that IF on it.

I have tried to get the If statement to work on it's own in an independent cell by itself and that doesn't work either.

Comment: I would help if you could create a spreadsheet with realistic sample data and desired result (manually inputed).

Answer (score 0):

instead of your:

```
=IF("E7=0", "E7", "Seek Additional Resources")
```

use:

```
=IF(E7*1=0, E7, "Seek Additional Resources")
```

see: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471